# disintegration of infinite convex combination of measures

Tags: probability, measure-theory

One expects that the disintegration (under a map $X \to Y$) of a convex combination of probability measures on X is the convex combination of disintegration of the measures. My question is if this can be stated rigorously and proved. I suspect that its proof is trivial once the correct statement is formulated, but I am stuck at how to state it precisely.

**Background**

($M(X)$ denotes the set of probability measures on $X$)

Given a Borel map $\pi: X \to Y$ between standard Borel spaces, any probability measure $\mu \in M(X)$ can be decomposed into two parts: its pushforward image $\pi \mu \in M(Y)$ and its disintegration $y \in Y \mapsto \mu_y \in M(X)$. The disintegration $y \mapsto \mu_y$ is unique in the $\pi\mu$-a.e. sense.

Now suppose $\mu \in M(X)$ is given as some infinite convex combination of other measures on X. In other words, suppose $\mu = \int_A \mu^\alpha\ d\rho(\alpha)$ where $A$ is another standard Borel space and $\alpha \in A \mapsto \mu^\alpha \in M(X)$ is a Borel map and $\rho \in M(A)$.

One can check that the pushforward image $\pi\mu$ is the $\rho$ convex combination of $\pi(\mu^\alpha)$. In other words, $$\pi\mu = \int_A \pi(\mu^\alpha) \ d\rho(\alpha)$$

And one then intuitively expects the following proposition:

> The disintegration $y \mapsto \mu_y$ is the $\rho$ convex combination
>   of the disintegration $y \mapsto (\mu^\alpha)_y$, in other words,
>   $$\mu_y = \int_A (\mu^\alpha)_y \ d\rho(\alpha)$$

But the integrand on the right side does not seem measurable and even if it is measurable, perturbing each $y \mapsto (\mu^\alpha)_y$ on a $\pi(\mu^\alpha)$-null set can perturb $y \mapsto \int_A (\mu^\alpha)_y \ d\rho(\alpha)$ on the whole Y (this issue can be demonstrated with a simple example with finite $A$), so the proposition as stated is false. How should I modify the proposition to make it true?

**Example demonstrating the issue**

Let $\mu = \frac12 \mu^1 + \frac12 \mu^2$ where $\mu^1, \mu^2 \in M([0,1]\times[0,1])$ are the uniform distributions on $[0,1]\times [0,\frac12]$, $[0,1]\times [\frac12, 1]$ respectively. Then $\mu$ is the uniform distribution on the unit square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Denote by $\lambda$ the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, i.e., the Lebesgue measure restricted to $[0,1]$. Denote by $\delta_y$ the Dirac measure on $y \in [0,1]$.
The map $y \mapsto \mu^1_y$ defined by
$$\mu^1_y = 
\begin{cases}
  \lambda \times \delta_y & \text{if } y \in [0,\frac12] \\
  \delta_0 \times \delta_0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is a disintegration of $\mu^1$ w.r.t. the 2nd projection map $\pi: [0,1]\times [0,1] \to [0,1]$ defined by $\pi(x,y) = y$.

Similarly, the map $y \mapsto \mu^2_y$ defined by
$$\mu^2_y = 
\begin{cases}
  \lambda \times \delta_y & \text{if } y \in [\frac12,1] \\
  \delta_0 \times \delta_0 & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
is a disintegration of $\mu^2$ w.r.t. the same $\pi$.

On the other hand, the map $y \mapsto \frac12 \mu^1_y + \frac12 \mu^2_y$ is not a disintegration of $\mu$ w.r.t. $\pi$.

Comment: I'll try to take a closer look tomorrow, but disintegration is just a special case of a product measure - can you show it for products? From what I recall, it shall hold on Borel spaces.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can assume that $A = M(X)$ since the latter is also a Borel space, so that we can integrate over it. Second, Lemma 2.2 [here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2001688?sid=21104987907161&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3738736) shows that you can choose $\mu^\alpha_x$ to be jointly measurable in both arguments. With this in hand, did you try just directly checking that $\int \mu^\alpha \rho(\mathrm d\alpha)$ satisfies all the desired properties of the disintegration?

Comment: The issue seems to persist even when $\mu^\alpha_x$ is jointly measurable. I've added an example demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @JisangYoo: I think, you are right: there shall be a Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{\mathrm d\mu^\alpha}{\mathrm d\int \mu^\alpha\rho(\mathrm d\alpha)}$ which is a function of $x$ and $\alpha$. You can check how does it apply in your case. The point is that $\mu^\alpha \ll \int \mu^\alpha\rho(\mathrm d\alpha)$ only holds $\rho$-a.e. and that may depend on $x$, so it's indeed tricky to say whether such derivative always exist. For countable combinations everything shall work fine.